# ASP.NET MVC - How to stop rendering of a view childactions on Autharization error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

In an Umbraco project I have a controller which requires user to be in a particular role, and a view with many child actions. When user with insufficient access rights tries to access the page then they should see an error message. Sofar I have created a customized Authorize attribute like this:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
            else if (!AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
            {
                ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
                viewData.Add("AuthenticationeError", "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this content.");
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/AuthError.cshtml", ViewData = viewData };                
            }
        }
```

It does the job, although with the following error. On page load the view calls three different child actions from the secured controller and every time it does this, a new authorization error ViewResult is being displayed. Can this behavior be stopped? I want to render only one Error message and stop further view processing after the first error. Also I'd like user to stay on same page and avoid redirects if possible

Answer (score 0):

For ChildAction I ended up returning empty ContentResult. The most simplified version of this is:

```
if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
{
    filterContext.Result = new ContentResult() { Content = "" };
}
```

This doesn't answers my original question but solves the problem